# FragmentPagerAdapter and notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-adapter

How can I use `notifyDataSetChanged` with `FragmentPagerAdapter` ?

In `onResume`:
I used `mMyFragmentPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` but it didnt worked

But  
`mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());`
 is worked

```
    public class Activity extends FragmentActivity{

     static ViewPager mViewPager;  
        private MyFragmentPagerAdapter mMyFragmentPagerAdapter;  
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);  
            mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());  
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);  
}  
     private static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter { 
    ...
    }

    @Override
       protected void onResume() {
           super.onResume();

    //WORKS     
             mMyFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());        
         mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);  

    //DOESN'T WORK
     mMyFragmentPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     mViewPager.setAdapter(mMyFragmentPagerAdapter);     

           }
       }
```

Populate:

```
 public void startView() {
 this.questions.clear();  // this.questions is a LinkedList
 this.questions.add(q);

    }
```

Comment: are you populating your adapter with new data anywhere?

Comment: yes, I'm populating it from an external class

Comment: can you please post some more code how actually you are populating your adapter from an external class?

Comment: added code. I'm using questions- LinedList in fragment (Its only one fragment and auto updates content when position changed - updates List items) , I populate all list items.

Comment: are you sure that your startView is getting called before onResume() ?

Comment: In an external class I use :
                `this.startView();
                this.finish(); `
               Then It goes onResume ( I think ? )

Comment: Are you overriding getItemPosition in MyFragmentPagerAdapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to update a ListView / ViewPager or any other kind of view and it's adapter,you need to requery the `Cursor` for example if you are using it to populate the view. So as in your situation, you have a `ViewPager` and an `Adapter`. So the first thing which you consider is the way you update your `LinkedList`. In your situations you are doing it right, but in my opinion `this.quetions` in your external class is different than the `LinkedList` you are using to populate your adapter. In this case I would suggest you don't use external class to update your adapter. If that is too hard to achieve depending on the code organisation, just be sure that you are using the same `LinkedList` in your `Fragment` and external class.

Answer (score 1):

Change your adapter extends `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and then the `notifyDataSetChanged` work fine.
It's work for me.